# How I can display Stream on the page?

Tags: c#, wcf, filestream

I have a WCF method that I am calling, the method suppose to create a file but it create an exception. I try to find what is in the stream request that I am passing to this method. How I can alert or write this stream so I can find the content. That is my method:

```
    Stream UploadImage(Stream request)
    {

        Stream requestTest = request;



        HttpMultipartParser parser = new HttpMultipartParser(request, "data");
        string filePath = "";
        string passed = "";
        if (parser.Success)
        {


            // Save the file somewhere 
            //File.WriteAllBytes(FILE_PATH + title + FILE_EXT, parser.FileContents);

            // Save the file 
            //SaveFile( mtp.Filename, mtp.ContentType, mtp.FileContents);
            FileStream fileStream = null;
            BinaryWriter writer = null;


            try
            {


                filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Uploded\\test.jpg");  // BuildFilePath(strFileName, true);    
                filePath = filePath.Replace("SSGTrnService\\", "");

                fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
```

it produces an error on this line :

fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);

that I try to understand why file can not created.

Comment: Can you please update the question with the exception that you receive?

Answer (score 0):

Given the information you gave, I can only assume that your code tries to create the file `test.jpg` somewhere where your application is not allowed to write. A common mistake would be somewhere in the `Program files` folder. In modern Windows versions, that is specially protected.

Comment: actually it is working when I call it by regular HTML but I am sending a stream from Android app and it is not working so I wonder maybe I am not sending a wight thing so I want to see what I am sending.

Comment: With the line `fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);`, you do not send anything at all. You merely create a file at `filePath`. You said that this is what produces the error. And you still did not give us the error itself :)

Comment: oh ok error is: object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: And you are absolutely sure that it comes from that line? The one where you instanciate the `FileStream`? Because that would mean that your `filePath` variable would be null, and that would actually already be thrown in the line before that.

Comment: actually I have put number to see where error is produced: so I get error exactly after this line: fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the line after that? The code you gave ends there.

Comment: fileStream.Write(parser.FileContents, 0,parser.FileContents.Length);            catch (Exception ex){return "Error: " + ex.Message;}                  
                finally
                {
                 if (fileStream != null)
                  fileStream.Close();
                    if (writer != null)
                        writer.Close();} }
                                       string text = "Image uploaded: " + parser.Filename + " / " + parser.ContentType + filePath;